# add a layout on top of another layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm a new programmer, I'm trying to add a winner Layout on top of another layout, however the winner Layout becomes transparent (behind the game layout) 
I'm not sure how to fix that.. 
The design of the  winner Layout was copied from another layout which there I don't have this kind of problem
any ideas how can I fix that?[`my problem`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmzs3.png)

```
messageForWinnerLayout.setVisibility(linearLayout.VISIBLE);
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageForWinnerLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/closeImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
            android:onClick="ok"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/x" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/haveWinnerTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="We Have A Winner!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/winnerMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:text="Close"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Parent layout as **RelativeLayout**, by using RelativeLayout we can add view on Top of the another Child view.